# How to categorize continuous data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have two dependent continuous variables and i want to use their combined values to predict the value of a third binary variable. How do i go about discretizing/categorizing the values? I am not looking for clustering algorithms,  i'm specifically interested in obtaining 'meaningful' discrete categories i can subsequently use in in a Bayesian classifier. 
Pointers to papers, books, online courses, all very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That is the essence of machine learning and problem one of the most studied problem.

Least-square regression, logistic regression, SVM, random forest are widely used for this type of problem, which is called binary classification.

If your goal is to pragmatically classify your data, several libraries are available, like Scikits-learn in python and weka in java. They have a great documentation.

But if you want to understand what's the intrinsics of machine learning, just search (here or on google) for machine learning resources.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear it is about categorisation specifically not about classification in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be a real nerd, generate a bunch of different possible discretizations and then train a classifier on it, and then characterize the discretizations by features and then run a classifier on that, and see what sort of discretizations are best!?

In general discretizing stuff is more of an art and having a good understanding of what the input variable ranges mean.